# Apache error - Port 443 in use

Tags: apache-http-server

When I try to start Apache, I receive the following error:

```
Problem detected!
9:49:19 AM [Apache] Port 443 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 2028!
9:49:19 AM [Apache] Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
9:49:19 AM [Apache] You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
9:49:19 AM [Apache] or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
9:49:19 AM [main] The Mercury module is disabled
9:49:19 AM [main] The Tomcat module is disabled.
```

Also getting this in error logs.

```
[Mon Feb 02 09:22:56.084469 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 2028:tid 444] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Feb 02 09:22:56.177793 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 2028:tid 444] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Feb 02 09:22:56.227829 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2028:tid 444] AH00455: Apache/2.4.7 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1e PHP/5.5.9 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Feb 02 09:22:56.227829 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2028:tid 444] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Nov 21 2013 20:13:01
[Mon Feb 02 09:22:56.227829 2015] [core:notice] [pid 2028:tid 444] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Mon Feb 02 09:22:56.243855 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2028:tid 444] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 1384
[Mon Feb 02 09:22:56.677146 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 1384:tid 348] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Feb 02 09:22:56.741192 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 1384:tid 348] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Feb 02 09:22:56.921894 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1384:tid 348] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

Any help is appreciated. I am taking an online course in SQL and PHP and I can't even get off the ground.

Comment: Check what port is using 443. If there aren't any, open port 443. If it's already open, `sudo service apache2 restart`, it might be running already.

Comment: @Chipperyman good point, but looks like Windows, not *nix from the log files, so he'll have to restart service using `services.msc` instead.

Comment: Sorry such a layman, guys.  Checked port 443.  Its open and I cant see anything using it.  Kristian, I checked to restart in services but unless its listed as something other than apache, Im not seeing it.

Comment: am I looking for apache or should i be looking for something else within services?

Comment: how did you check 443? somthing like `netstat -abno | FINDSTR LISTENING | FINDSTR 443`?

Comment: Frank,  I opened CMD prompt and ran netstat.  It listed alot of IP addresses, foreign addresses, etc.  I must be looking at the wrong thing by the reading of your comment.  Like I said, I am trying a class and I just need to get apache running at this point and cant even get thtat far :(

Comment: Just ask your professor

Comment: well, with netstat you are looking for a LISTENING port (one that can accept incoming connections to a service) so the FINDSTR command just filters the output to show you only what you are looking for; a listener on port 443. if you are seeing 443 in netstat, it is probably the listener, but it doesn't hurt to check. That you can't identify the process listening on 443 is odd. do you have another webserver running on that port?

Comment: Do you have VMWare Workstation installed? That program also uses the port 443.

Answer (score 1):

The 2nd line from the bottom...

```
RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
```

... means that you have not set the `ServerName` and left it with the example text